# SKNode not moving to programmed position

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sknode

I have created an SKNode class that works perfectly fine. However, I can't change its .position after I have instantiated.

The button does appear and function correctly but simply doesn't change position when programmed to. I have included the class made for the button below, I have also added the code to which I instantiate the class and call the nodes position.

class code:

```
class LButton: SKNode {
    var button: SKSpriteNode
    private var mask: SKSpriteNode
    private var cropNode: SKCropNode
    private var action: () -> Void
    var isEnabled = true
    
   
    
    init(imageNamed: String, buttonAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        button.size = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0*(24/40))
        
        mask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.black, size: button.size)
        mask.alpha = 0
        
        cropNode = SKCropNode()
        cropNode.maskNode = button
        cropNode.zPosition = 3
        cropNode.addChild(mask)
        
        action = buttonAction
        
        super.init()
        
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        setupNodes()
        addNodes()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupNodes() {
        button.zPosition = 0
    }
    
    func addNodes() {
        addChild(button)
        addChild(cropNode)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isEnabled {
            mask.alpha = 0.5
            run(SKAction.scale(by: 1.05, duration: 0.05))
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isEnabled {
            for touch in touches {
                let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
                
                if button.contains(location){
                    mask.alpha = 0.5
                    
                } else {
                    mask.alpha = 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isEnabled {
            for touch in touches {
                let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
                
                if button.contains(location) {
                    disable()
                    action()
                    run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.2), SKAction.run({self.enable()})]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func disable() {
        isEnabled = false
        mask.alpha = 0.0
        button.alpha = 0.5
    }
    
    func enable() {
        isEnabled = true
        mask.alpha = 0.0
        button.alpha = 1.0
    }
    
}
```

instantiation code:

```
var playButtonTwo: LButton {
        let revealGameScene = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
        let goToGameScene = GameSceneTwo(size: self.size)
        goToGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill
        
        var button = LButton(imageNamed: "playButton", buttonAction: {        self.view?.presentScene(goToGameScene, transition:revealGameScene)
        })
        
        button.zPosition = 5
        button.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width*0.3, y: self.frame.height*0.4)
        return button
    }
```

calling to change nodes position:

```
playButtonTwo.position = CGPoint(x:0, y: -self.frame.height*0.4)
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: "calling to change nodes position"  Where and how are you calling it?

Comment: This is code is placed in didMove and should run when the SKScene loads.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should not set the position of the button inside the creation of it. Instead just position it in didMove

```
var playButtonTwo: LButton {
    let revealGameScene = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
    let goToGameScene = GameSceneTwo(size: self.size)
    goToGameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill

    var button = LButton(imageNamed: "playButton", buttonAction: {        self.view?.presentScene(goToGameScene, transition:revealGameScene)
    })

    button.zPosition = 5
    // button.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width*0.3, y: self.frame.height*0.4) <- comment out his line 
    return button
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately when I call the position in didMove rather than inside the creation of it. The button still doesn't move to the desired position but remains at the centre of the screen.

Comment: I think I may have an idea of the problem. Because how playButtonTwo is initialised it is a get only variable so its values cant be changed. However, I dont know the solution to fixing this.